# Converting weekly data entered horizontally by month to a vertical list

Tags: google-sheets

I have YEARS of sales data that I need to make into a vertical list in order to make usable.  I've tried combinations of vlookup, hlookup, and index/match, but cannot find the right combination.

Here's the example:
[image]

I need the resulting data to appear like:

[image]

Listing out all the Weeks as a reference to pull the sales data from is not a problem at all.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula:

`=SORT(TRANSPOSE(
{SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("-",1,FILTER(data,ISODD(COLUMN(data)))),"-");
SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("-",1,FILTER(data,ISEVEN(COLUMN(data)))),"-")}))`

replace "data" with your range `A4:F8` or make your own named range called "data".

[image]

Comment: Tried your solution and received this error:   In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows.

Comment: The ";" was the issue. Changed your formula to: =SORT(TRANSPOSE(
{SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("-",1,FILTER(data,ISODD(COLUMN(data)))),"-"),
SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("-",1,FILTER(data,ISEVEN(COLUMN(data)))),"-")}))  But the data isn't lining up correctly.  Everything is in a single column.

Comment: Your answer pointed me in the right direction.  I had to TRANSPOSE the data twice and remove the SORT.  Please edit your answer to:  **={transpose(split(textjoin("-",1,transpose(FILTER(data,ISODD(COLUMN(data))))),"-")),transpose(split(textjoin("-",1,transpose(FILTER(data,ISEVEN(COLUMN(data))))),"-"))}** and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: My formula works ok, please see screenshot. I cannot reproduce your error.   
The ";" was not the issue, I wanted to place data one behind the other. Could you please share your sheet with tests? Anyway you could upvote the answer as useful.

Comment: You're right! It did work.  I HAD to use a named range.  The error only occurs when I entered in the range from another sheet without naming it.  Marked as accepted.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

A long, But easy solution will be

```
 = ARRAYFORMULA({{A4:B7};{C4:D7};{E4:F7}.....})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this too:

```
  =OFFSET($A$4, MOD(ROW(A7),7),(CEILING((ROW(B1))/7)*2)-2,1,2)
```

Drag fill down.

- There are a couple of things you need to change here:  the maximum length of a single column. For eg, If January has a maximum number of rows, say 15, then, then maximum number of rows needs to inputted accordingly:

MOD(ROW (A`15`),`15`), and CEILING((ROW(B1))/`15`)

- You'll have blanks. Try UNIQUE on the resulting column to remove blanks.